# Help with FTP and TFTP

Tags: ftp, tftp

Can someone explain the use FTP/TFTP? I understand the commands and how to use it some what but Im just confused on the server aspect I guess. Do you need to setup a FTP/TFTP server before you can even use it or is that for just another function.

Im in the middle of trying to flash my router with DD-WRT for the first time and just didn't want to futz it up after all the work I put into it. I would like to mess around with it more for just sending files but just confused on the whole setting it up before hand, if I even have to.

Comment: What does flashing your router have to do with 1. ftp and 2. ubuntu?

Comment: 1. Because Im going to be using the TFTP function of Ubuntu lol

Answer (score 0):

> Do you need to setup a FTP/TFTP server before you can even use it

Yes.

When you want to copy from and to Ubuntu `scp` is more convenient (`scp` used `ssh`). Also requires installing of server software to make it possible though.

Comment: Ok thanks. Upgrading my Linksys router with the DD-WRT firmware and I have to use the TFTP in order to send the new binary MAC address to the router after the flash. Router will be directly connected to my laptop so wasnt sure if needed to configure an TFTP server bofore hand